# MacBook Pro Retina 13": change resolution to 1920x1200 pixels

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

How can I change the resolution of my MacBook Pro 13" Retina (Late 2013) to 1920x1200 pixels?

The MacBook is able to use this resolution! It's e.g. using it, when connecting a second display which uses 1920x1200 pixels and checking the 'mirror displays' option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Retina DisplayMenu, QuickRes or SwitchResX.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in display should have a native resolution of [2560x1600](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-13-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html).  So it should support 1920x1200 @1.3x.

You can use the [displaymode](https://github.com/p00ya/displaymode) command line tool to change the resolution.

Download the binary from the "releases" section, and extract it if necessary.  Then from Terminal.app, `cd` to the directory the `displaymode` file is in.  With any secondary displays unplugged, run:

```
./displaymode t 1920 1200
```

Answer (score -1):

Although you could do that, I would not recommend to do that. The font and everything else will be very small and it will be hard to read. It also could cause high temperatures on your macbook.

Comment: I run a 2018 MacBook Pro at native resolution and I haven't noticed any problems with heat (ambient temperature typically < 30C).  I suspect the GPU still does most of the work to scale to Retina even with the lower resolutions selected.